# Visitor pattern: Number arithmetics based on input

Tags: c#, design-patterns, arithmetic-expressions, visitor-pattern

Let's say we have the following data hierarchy in C# to evaluate mathematic (prefix) expressions in `int` arithmetics:

```
abstract class Expression {
        public abstract int Evaluate();
}

class ValueExpression : Expression {
    public int Value {
        get;
    }

    public sealed override int Evaluate() {
        return Value;
    }
}

abstract class OperatorExpression : Expression {
    // ...
}

abstract class BinaryExpression : OperatorExpression {
    protected Expression op0, op1;

    public Expression Op0 {
        get { return op0; }
        set { op0 = value; }
    }

    public Expression Op1 {
        get { return op1; }
        set { op1 = value; }
    }

    public sealed override int Evaluate() {
        return Evaluate(op0.Evaluate(), op1.Evaluate());
    }

    protected abstract int Evaluate(int op0Value, int op1Value);
}

sealed class PlusExpression : BinaryExpression {
    protected override int Evaluate(int op0Value, int op1Value) {
        return checked(op0Value + op1Value);
    }
} // and more operators...
```

How could I use the visitor pattern to evaluate an expression and write out a result as `int` or `double` based on the user input? I thought I might write a Visitor class that holds `double result;` and each `Visit(...)` would evaluate the (sub)expression using `double` arithmetics and then I would convert the result to `int` if needed. But is this the best solution to this using visitor pattern? What if I wanted to use `long` later on? It would be necessary to modify the classes by non-trivial amount of code, or? (Note: I would like to use visitor pattern (and not the dynamic one) and not any generic code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead the `int Evaluate()` I created `void Accept(IExpressionVisitor visitor)` function. The `PlusExpression` class looked like this now:

```
sealed class PlusExpression : BinaryExpression
{
    public override void Accept(IExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}
```

Then I created two visitors deriving from `IExpressionVisitor`. For example the visitor for integer arithmetics looks like this:

```
class ExpressionIntVisitor : IExpressionVisitor
{
    Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();

    public int GetRetVal()
    {
        return stack.Peek();
    }

    public void Visit(LiteralExpression exp)
    {
        stack.Push(exp.Value);
    }

    public void Visit(PlusExpression exp)
    {
        exp.Op0.Accept(this);
        exp.Op1.Accept(this);
        int b = stack.Pop();
        int a = stack.Pop();

        stack.Push(checked(a + b));
    }
```

Note: The `Stack` is not really necessary as it contains at most 2 values.

For the double arithmetics it is almost the same. Now we call `Accept(intVisitor)` or `Accept(doubleVisitor)`depending on what we need.